# How to include a radio-button and a text field in a same if/else function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, user-input

I’m new in coding. Maybe it a basics question, but still... 
I have a number field which assigns different values to another field with if / else statements, depending on the entered value (number >80 assigns 1, number between 50 and 80 assigns 2 and numbers <50 assigns 3). I have also a radio button, which, if checked, must assign a value (in my case “4”) to the same field and if the radio-button is checked it mustn’t allowed any change trough the number field (4 stays as an assigned value, no matter what number is or will be entered in number field). 
Both codes worked separately, but I have a problem to merge them together. 
Your help is appreciated.
V

**EDIT**: I edited the code after the comment from Sumeet, but this doesn’t solve my original question - how to include both in a same if/else statement?

```
<input id="testscore" type="number" name="testscore">Test score
<br />
<input id="final" type=“text” name="final" readonly="true">Final score class
<br />
<input id="radio1" class="radio" type="radio" name="test" value="4">yes
<input id="radio2" class="radio" type="radio" name="test" value="0">no
<br />


function getFinalScore() {
  var testScore = parseFloat($("#testscore").val());
  if (testScore >80){
    $('#final').val(1);
  } else if (testScore <=80 && testScore >50){
    $('#final').val(2);
  } else {
    $('#final').val(3);
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testscore').keyup(function(event) {
    getFinalScore();
  });
});

$('input').click(function(e){
  if $("#radio1").is(':checked')){
    $("#final").val(4);
  } else {
    $("#final").val(0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `$(radio1).is(':checked')` instead of `$("#radio1").is(':checked')`

```js
function getFinalScore() {
  var testScore = parseFloat($("#testscore").val());
  if (testScore >80){
    $('#final').val(1);
  } else if (testScore <=80 && testScore >50){
    $('#final').val(2);
  } else {
    $('#final').val(3);
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testscore').keyup(function(event) {
    getFinalScore();
  });
});

$('input').click(function(e){
  if ($("#radio1"). is(':checked')){
    $("#final").val(4);
    $('#testscore').prop( "disabled", true );
  } else {
    $('#testscore').prop( "disabled", false );
    $("#final").val(0);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="testscore" type="number" name="testscore">Test score
<br />
<input id="final" type=“text” name="final" readonly="true">Final score class
<br />
<input id="radio1" class="radio" type="radio" name="test" value="4">yes
<input id="radio2" class="radio" type="radio" name="test" value="0">no
<br />
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a typos, but this doesn’t solve my original question.

Comment: what is your problem then? explain pls

Comment: My problem is this: I need a mandatory value assignment to the field “final” if the radio button is selected, meaning input that must not be changed trough the user input in the field “testscore”. Example radio button means dead/alive and the number input is like number of respiration’s for a minute. It is obvious that is someone is dead number of respiration’s is like 0. I couldn’t add the radio button in the if/else sequence of the function. I hope that I explained it good.

Answer (score 0):

try it: [codepen](https://codepen.io/piotrazsko/pen/WXXQzX)

You can use `document.querySelector('#radio1').checked` instead `$("#radio1").is(':checked')`

Comment: Hi, thanks, your answer is good and the code works, but my problem is that I need a mandatory value assignment if the radio button is selected. I mean after I check the radio button it assigns “4” and them when I change the input value it changes the “4” to some other value according to if/else statements in the function. I need this “4” to stay there no matter what the input is.